# Polynomial regression with scikit learn vs np.polyfit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am quite surprised that nobody talks about this: the difference of polynomial regression done with scikit learn vs polyfit from numpy.

First, the data:

```
xdic={'X': {11: 300, 12: 170, 13: 288, 14: 360, 15: 319, 16: 330, 17: 520, 18: 345, 19: 399, 20: 479}}
ydic={'y': {11: 305000, 12: 270000, 13: 360000, 14: 370000, 15: 379000, 16: 405000, 17: 407500, 18: 450000, 19: 450000, 20: 485000}}

X=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xdic)
y=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ydic)
import numpy as np
X_seq = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),300).reshape(-1,1)
```

Then let's create the model with scikit learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

degree=9

polyreg=make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree),
                      LinearRegression())
polyreg.fit(X,y)
```

Then you can create a plot

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X_seq,polyreg.predict(X_seq),color="black")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot

[image]

With numpy, it is quite different.

```
coefs = np.polyfit(X.values.flatten(), y.values.flatten(), 9)

X_seq = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),300)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_seq, np.polyval(coefs, X_seq), color="black")
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.show()
```

With the plot we can see that the results are quite different.

[image]

It may seem that it is due to foating point imprecision...

Answer (score 2):

I used both of them, and got the same R2 score and the same curve

```
regr = LinearRegression()
cubic = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_cubic = cubic.fit_transform(dfa3.home_realshow_cnt.values.reshape(-1, 1))
regr = regr.fit(X_cubic,dfa3.prop)

sklearn_r2=r2_score(dfa3.prop,regr.predict(X_cubic))
fit_r2=r2_score(dfa3.prop,yvalsa)
print("sklearn_r2: ",sklearn_r2,'; fit_r2: ',fit_r2)
```

```
def fit(x,y,n):
    z1 = np.polyfit(x,y, n)
    p1 = np.poly1d(z1)
    return p1(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the code, it appears that both methods use a least square solver for equation `Ax=y`. The solver seems to be different:

- for scikit-learn, they use [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html)
- for numpy, it seems that [they implement their own solver](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#L3993).

While the solver implementation are not the same, the biggest difference seems to be that [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) rescale the left hand side of the equation (the part containing power of `x`). You can look into the source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L453-L698) (from line 667 to 670).

In small dimension, both coefficient set match. When dimension increases, it starts to shift. I ran some experiments (computing the log of distance between coefficients), taking the median over a thousand generated different set of (X, y), with `X.shape = degree`, I have:

```bash
|   degree |   log(coeff dist) (median) |
|---------:|---------------------------:|
|        1 |                    -inf    |
|        2 |                     -24.26 |
|        3 |                     -21.28 |
|        4 |                     -17.02 |
|        5 |                     -12.95 |
|        6 |                      -7.58 |
|        7 |                      -3.55 |
|        8 |                       0.76 |
|        9 |                       5.39 |
|       10 |                       9.32 |
```

Note that it also depends on the magnitude of your `(X, y)`. For this example, I took the same magnitude as your (`X ~ 10` and `y ~ 10**5`). As, `polyfit` produces the solution expected (going to every provided coordinates), we should try to rescale `X`.

Providing a rescaled `X` into the `LinearRegression` (note that you should use `fit_intercept=False`, since `PolynomFeatures` returns `X**0 -> X**degree`, then `X**0` coefficient is the intercept), you find approximately the same coefficient using both operators.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. Indeed, it does seem like it can come from floating point precision issues. In my case I had large x values (~60000) which were then taken to the 4th power in my PolynomialFeatures. By running my sklearn pipeline through a standard scaler first I was able to capture the same result as I did without scaling using numpy's polyfit. Otherwise they were having very different numerics.